# What is an anonymous inline box?

Tags: html, css

[A website](https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=00700-ab980c45-44be-41d6-9869-4c8290bbfc7c) was explaining about something called an "anonymous inline box" and has this example:

```
<p> Some <em> emphasize </em> text </p>
```

> The block-level box generated by the p element only contains inline elements. The inline box of the text "emphsize" is formed by the `<em>` tag, so it is not an anonymous box, and the text "Some" and "text" do not have corresponding tags to wrap them, so Surrounding them is the anonymous inline box.

Can I say that any text that is not wrapped inside the tags are anonymous box or is it just true for this situation?

I would appreciate if you could help me understand it a little better.

Comment: This page about the [CSS Visual Formatting Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) may be helpful. I've been writing HTML/CSS for over 10 years and had never heard of an "anonymous box", so I'm not sure it's functionally important knowledge.

Comment: @Sean it's a *very* important concept that you deal with everyday but you are not necessary aware of. Understand "anonymous box" and similar concept can help you understand CSS correctly

Comment: Can you share what you were reading?  I'm a web developer and I've never heard of "anonymous boxes."  If you share the link, then we should be able to help explain it :-)

Comment: @TemaniAfif So, what is an "anonymous box?"

Comment: It's always a good idea to cite your sources, so that others can understand the situation. For instance, there might be some context you've left out that would provide others more insight into what the author meant by the phrase in question.

Comment: @RocketHazmat https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous

Comment: @RocketHazmat it is actually discussed in the [MDN CSS Visual Formatting Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Visual_formatting_model) that Sean shared.  Upon inspection, it appears to be the automatic creation of boxes by display layouts in cases in which there is no markup to create them.

Comment: @AlexanderNied (and @TemaniAfif) Thanks!  That's helpful.  Never heard that term, but I always like learning new stuff :-)

Comment: So a textNode..... seems odd to call it that.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes

Comment: @epascarello not really odd. CSS is all about "boxes" and you have the ones that are "explicit" and the ones that the browser create implicitly (called anonymous because we cannot reach for them). All the boxes and then used to create the final layout

Comment: Interestingly the link from @TemaniAfif has the same example, but it says those same boxes are anonymous inline boxes generated by the block-level paragraph element. So it's not so much that they are boxes that don't have tags (they do, `p`), it's that they are broken up by the named inline box created by the `em`. I'm guessing that `Text` in `<p>Text</p>` is not an anonymous inline box, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @HereticMonkey even in that case we have an anonymous inline box for text because p will generate a block-level box while text should be an inline one so we need a box for it.

Comment: Thanks, @TemaniAfif After I wrote that I was reading the link Sean provided. Looks like the browser's generating boxes all the time -- it's boxes all the way down. :)

Comment: thank you all for answering and helping me out

Comment: Just to confuse matters, "some" and "text" generate separate anonymous inline boxes according to the CSS2 specification. According to the CSS 3 Inline layout specification they belong to _the same_ anonymous inline box. Also, inline and block level are not the only types of anonymous box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the text your read comes from https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous

> **9.2.2.1 Anonymous inline boxes**
> Any text that is directly contained inside a block container element (not inside an inline element) must be treated as an anonymous inline element.
>
> In a document with HTML markup like this:
> `<p>Some <em>emphasized</em> text</p>`
> the `<p>` generates a block box, with several inline boxes inside it. The box for "emphasized" is an inline box generated by an inline element (`<em>`), but the other boxes ("Some" and "text") are inline boxes generated by a block-level element (`<p>`). The latter are called anonymous inline boxes, because they do not have an associated inline-level element.
>
> Such anonymous inline boxes inherit inheritable properties from their block parent box. Non-inherited properties have their initial value. In the example, the color of the anonymous inline boxes is inherited from the P, but the background is transparent.
>
> White space content that would subsequently be collapsed away according to the 'white-space' property does not generate any anonymous inline boxes.
>
> If it is clear from the context which type of anonymous box is meant, both anonymous inline boxes and anonymous block boxes are simply called anonymous boxes in this specification.
>
> There are more types of anonymous boxes that arise when formatting [tables](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#anonymous-boxes).

```css
p {
  background-color: red
}

em {
  background-color: yellow
}
```

```html
<p> Anonymous inline box #1 <em> inline emphasized box </em> Anonymous inline box #2 </p>
```